# How to read a text file continuously in Windows Service

Tags: c#, io, windows-services, text-files, streamreader

I am reading a text file in windows Service .As per my requirement i have to read the text file line by line and process the contents of the line and insert into the database.The nature of the text file is such that it is constantly getting updated.Sometimes in a span of minute 100 lines will get added and sometimes no.So there is no fixed rate at which lines are getting inserted into the text file.
At present i am reading the text file using `StreamReader` line by line with while loop but as soon as line gets over it comes back.Here is my structure of windows Service.

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private System.Threading.Thread _thread;
    private ManualResetEvent _shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public void OnDebug()
    {
        OnStart(null);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _thread = new Thread(parseAndProcess);
        _thread.Start();
    }
    public void parseAndProcess()
    {      
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(FileToCopy) == true)
        {

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileToCopy))
            {

                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line != "")
                    {
                       //line processing logic goes here            
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
            } 
       }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
         _shutdownEvent.Set();
        _thread.Join();  // wait for thread to stop
    }
}
}
```

This is the entire structure of my windows Service.Here reading stops if there is no next line in the text file available for that time and it will be stopped until the service is restarted which i dont want to do.
So how can i check for file updation in case streamreader gets stopped reading lines.

Here is my updated code with FileSystemWatcher

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        _thread = new Thread(parseAndProcess);
        _thread.Start();


        FileSystemWatcher Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher("File Path");
        Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        Watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(Watcher_Changed);



    }

    // This event is raised when a file is changed
    private void Watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        _thread = new Thread(parseAndProcess);
        _thread.Start();
    }
```

In this Code i have a doubt will my how to read only new lines added into the textfile when getting invoked by FileSystemWatcher Changed Event.
Please help.

Comment: You can try using [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class and [`Changed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed(v=vs.110).aspx) event to monitor changes to the desired file.

Comment: @Yuriy How will i read the newly added line using this?

Comment: @Yuriy I have updated my code with FileSystemWatcher and changed event.Is is right way?if yes:how can i read only newly added lines of text file.

Answer (score 1):

Create a private copy of the file, that way the file is open to be changed by other processes.

Process the copy.

Delete the copy.

If the original file has changed (could use FileSystemWatcher) repeat and do not process lines that you already processed.

Detecting lines that you already processed might be the hardest but depends on the idempotency of the system and the actual content of the file.

Idempotency means that the system (database) you are feeding the lines to does not change when passing it the same line multiple times.

Recognizing the same line depends on the content of the line. It might be a line number, GUID, ID, Timestamp